# Spark Cassandra connector saveToCassandra() is sending data to driver and causing a OOM exception

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, driver, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to use the Spark Cassandra connector.

Here is my code:

```
   JavaRDD<UserStatistics> rdd=CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(sparkContext).cassandraTable(
            ConfigStore.read("cassandra", "keyspace"), "user_activity_" + type).where("bucket =?",
            date).select("user_id", "code").mapToPair(row -> new Tuple2<String, Integer>(row
            .getString("user_id"), 1)).reduceByKey((value1, value2) -> value1 + value2).map(s ->
    {
        List<UserStatistics> userStatistics = new ArrayList<>();
        UserStatistics userStatistic = new UserStatistics();
        userStatistic.setUser_id(s._1);
        userStatistic.setStatistics_type(type);
        long total = s._2;
        int failureCount = 0;//s._2._2().iterator().next();
        int selectedCount = 0; //s._2._2().iterator().next();
        userStatistic.setTotal_count((int) total);
        userStatistic.setFailure_count(failureCount);
        userStatistic.setSelected_count(selectedCount);
        userStatistics.add(userStatistic);
        return userStatistic;
    });
    CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(rdd).writerBuilder(ConfigStore.read("cassandra", "keyspace"),
            "user_statistics",mapToRow(UserStatistics.class)).saveToCassandra();
```

After I execute this, it outputs the follow. It eventually throws a OOM exception for the driver.
I am not sure why it is trying to send data to driver.

```
Executor: Finished task 1007.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1007). 84821 bytes result sent to driver
15/09/29 13:57:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1016.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1016, localhost, NODE_LOCAL, 2096 bytes)
15/09/29 13:57:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1007.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1007) in 78 ms on localhost (1009/640442)
15/09/29 13:57:32 INFO Executor: Running task 1016.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1016)
```

Comment: It is rather unlikely that 84821 bytes trigger OOM exception.

Comment: spark version? cassandra version? maybe a right permission to DB, or the port is blocked on localhost, check your iptables

Comment: spark 1.4 cassandra version :2.1.8 and connector :1.4.0-M1.

Comment: To key points:spark 1.4 cassandra version :2.1.8 and connector :1.4.0-M1. I look at all permissions, i can send /read data . if i use cassandra java  client from spark app . it is fine.  I can read data and write data.  Also My table is very small. it send lot of data to driver. As per my understanding it reads data on cluster does processing on cluster and then saves it back from cluster. It should require to send data to driver as i am not requesting any of those function like collect , count , take etc